# Django not creating database table after deleting migrations files and migration table

Tags: python, django

I have created two tables profile and details through django model and mistakenly i have deleted both these tables.
Further when i tried to create table using

```
python2.7 manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python2.7 manage.py migrate
```

then it was not creating the tables so i deleted migration files and truncated the django_migration table. Now when i am running command

```
python2.7 manage.py runserver
```

Its giving me error

```
You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

And if i run python manage.py migrate command error is

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: home, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
Rendering model states... DONE
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 59, in database_forwards
schema_editor.create_model(model)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 284, in create_model
self.execute(sql, params or None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" already exists
```

Comment: Now it is showing that django_content_type_app_label_76bd3d3b_uniq" already exists

Comment: You might want to rename your whole database and run the migrations again.

Comment: Is it the right way ? because i can't rename my database all tables and there is also some data in each table. Any alternate ?

Comment: even if you deleted tables from models.py and migrations the tables already exist in database

you can drop tables from the database and delete the migrations from migration table

Comment: @Dimitris First i deleted tables from database

Comment: What makes me think that you have upgraded django versions inbetween and forgot to tell us?

Answer (score 0):

Run following command:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

Comment: after running this command error is :-  django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist

Comment: once delete entire database and create new db then run migrat

Answer (score -1):

You need to first fake migrations for each of those built-in apps

**python manage.py migrate --fake auth**
**python manage.py migrate --fake contenttypes**

the run fake initial

**python manage.py migrate --fake-initial**

This most probably should work for you.